# If $a>0,A>0$, $f(x)\geq 0$ on $\Bbb R$, $f(x)+\int_{x-1}^xf(t)dt=A,\ \forall\ x\in\Bbb R$. Can we show $e^{ax}f(x)$ is increasing.

Tags: definite-integrals, monotone-functions

If $a,A$ are positive real numbers, $f(x)$ being nonnegative on $\Bbb R$, $f(x)+\int_{x-1}^xf(t)dt=A,\ \forall\ x\in\Bbb R$. Can we show $e^{ax}f(x)$ is increasing.

Roughly, if $f$ is differentiable, then $f'(x)+f(x)-f(x-1)=0$, thus $f'(x)+a f(x)\geq 0$, if $a\geq 1$. the result follows.

However, if $0<a<1$ or $f$ is not differentiable, can we still deduce that result?

Comment: Are $a,A$ real numbers? Is the relationship between $f$ and $A$ true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes..

Comment: If $e^{ax}f(x)$ increasing for all $a>0$ then $f$ is increasing itself (just by taking $a\to 0$ in the definition). However, the only monotonic solutions are constants.

Comment: @A.G. The problem is to show the monotonicity of $e^{ax}f(x)$ for fixed $a$. It is true?

Comment: @A.G. An idea is then to deduce from $f(x)+\int_{x-1}^xf(t)dt=A$ that $f$ is constant. Then the problem solves.

Comment: Since $\int_{x}^{x+1}f(t)\,dt=\int_{x-1}^xf(t+1)\,dt$, we have that

$$f(x+1)-f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x-\Big(f(t+1)-f(t)\Big)\,dt$$

and hence, with $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, we may write

$$g(x)=\int_{x-1}^x \int_{t-1}^t g(s)\,\,ds\,dt.$$

I don't know if this is useful, but I found it interesting nonetheless. Perhaps something can be found from this.